# Como uso order by em duas colunas na mesma tabela? Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Olá, estou com um problema e gostaria da ajuda de vocês. Sou iniciante com banco de dados e preciso fazer um relatório. O relatório é de todos os orçamentos organizados por cidade e por data. Queria mais ou menos assim:

```
Abatiá - 01/01/2019
Abatiá  - 02/01/2019
Abatiá  - 03/01/2019
Botucatu - 01/01/2019
Botucatu - 02/01/2019
```

Tenho esse sql que pego todas as infomações que preciso, porém eu só consigo ordenar por cidade, a data não fica ordenada, como resolvo isso?

O campo de data é do tipo Timestamp

```
SELECT id
      ,title
      ,description
      ,city
      ,created 
  FROM budget 
 WHERE created BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/01/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
   AND TO_DATE('30/12/2019','dd/mm/yyyy') 
 GROUP BY budget.city, budget.id 
 ORDER BY budget.created, budget.city ASC
```

Comment: Se você quer ordenar primeiro por cidade e depois por data então coloque esta ordem de campos na cláusula ORDER BY. Outra coisa é que você poderia simplificar utilizando: created BETWEEN DATE '2019-01-01' AND DATE '2019-12-30'.

Comment: Eu tentei fazer isso, a cidade funciona, fica em ordem alfabética certinho, mas a data não ordena, no resultado da query ela começa em julho de 2019, era pra começar de dezembro de 2018.

Comment: Inverte a ordem: ORDER BY budget.city ASC, budget.created ASC

Comment: @Benilson acontece igual comentei pro amigo ali em cima, a cidade fica certinho, mas a data começa em julho, era pra começar em dezembro do ano passado.

Comment: @anonimo opa, não sabia dessa abreviação, já estou usando aqui, obrigado. Agora preciso só ordenar a data que fica 100%

Comment: O where da consulta não vai permitir isso, o filtro está de 01/01/2019 até 30/12/2019, não vai permitir data menor que 2019.

Comment: @Benilson opa, é verdade, falha minha. Mas a ordenação começa em 07/29 e logo a baixo tem um na data 01/03

Comment: Na mesma cidade ou em cidades diferentes?

Comment: @Benilson Quando eu ordeno só por data primeiro `ORDER BY budget.city ASC, budget.created ASC` a cidade fica certo, mas a data não ordena. Já quando uso `ORDER BY budget.created ASC, budget.city ASC` acontece ao contrário, a data começa em janeiro certinho, só que a cidade não ordena.

Comment: @anonimo tipo, eu preciso saber quantos orçamentos teve em Abatiá, por exemplo, no mês de janeiro, logo em seguida a próxima cidade que começa com `B` em janeiro também, até acabar o mês de janeiro. E assim por diante, Cidades com `A` em `fevereiro`, depois `B` em `fevereiro` e tal..

Comment: @JonasGabriel O seu campo created é de qual tipo ?

Comment: @ChristianoRibeiroSoares é TIMESTAMP

Comment: Bom, então não é uma ordenação direta por cidade e data no período. Primeiro você quer ordenar por mês/ano, depois por nome da cidade e por fim por data (ou apenas o dia).

Comment: @anonimo isso mesmo, primeiro por mês (só desse ano) e depois por nome das cidades

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o campo `created` é efetivamente `TIMESTAMP` então utilize

```
SELECT id, title, description, city, created 
FROM budget WHERE created::DATE BETWEEN '2019-01-01'::DATE AND '2019-12-30'::DATE 
ORDER BY date_trunc('month', created), city, created;
```

ou ainda:

```
WHERE created BETWEEN TIMESTAMP '2019-01-01 00:00:00' AND TIMESTAMP '2019-12-30 23:59:59'
```

Comment: Nossa, perfeito, o segudo `WHERE` ficou melhor que o primeiro no meu caso. Muito obrigado!